# Terminal path bar style for prompt

Tags: terminal, command-line, design

I recently saw this in a demonstration online in someones Terminal:

[image: Path bar image]

Notice the path-bar-like style of the prompt, any ideas how you can get that? Some kind of customisation I'd assume?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dcondrey/f1187c2f7f51ed8daf85

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [Powerline](https://github.com/milkbikis/powerline-shell) which originally came about as a [Vim plugin](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline) (although the bash version has a different author). You need patched fonts to deal with the symbols. Like [these](https://gist.github.com/qrush/1595572)

Edit:

This screenshot is also using the [Solarized theme](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) I believe.

Comment: That looks like it, any idea what theme it is?

Comment: @Joshua see edit, my theme of choice as well

Answer (score 0):

The prompt is defined by the PS1 environment variable which you can define in your ~/.profile file.  For example to make it simply a "$" put this line in your .profile:

```
export PS1="$"
```

Then "source" (`source ~/.profile`) the file to make the changes active if you've edited it in a terminal or just open a new Terminal.

Details of the fancy special things you can insert there can be found by searching PS1, a good set of examples can be found at [The Geek Stuff](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-ps1-10-examples-to-make-your-linux-prompt-like-angelina-jolie/) most examples are for Linux but it's nearly the same (possibly identical not 100% sure though)